# Most efficient way to filter coordinates by distance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two lists/flat arrays `a` and `b` of 2D coordinates (x,y). (`a` contains up to ~1000 coordinates, `b` up to ~200,000.) I need to filter `b` to obtain a list of only those coordinates in `b` which are within a certain Euclidean distance, say 10, of any coordinate in `a`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

a = np.random.randint(50, size=(5, 2))
b = np.random.randint(50, size=(1000, 2))

def dist(coord_a, coord_b):
    squ_dist_x = (coord_a[0] - coord_b[0])**2
    squ_dist_y = (coord_a[1] - coord_b[1])**2
    return np.sqrt(squ_dist_x + squ_dist_y)

b_filter = []
for coord_b in b:
    for coord_a in a:
        distance = dist(coord_a, coord_b)
        if distance <= 5:
            b_filter.append(coord_b)
```

Output for `b_filter`:

```
[array([21, 30]),
 array([ 3, 30]),
 array([ 4, 30]),
 array([48, 32]),
 array([ 8, 32]),
 array([21, 32]),
 array([16, 30]),
 array([16, 30]),
 array([ 0, 32]),
 array([45, 32]),
 array([32, 30]),
 array([ 3, 31]),
 array([21, 30]),
 array([20, 31]),
 array([ 6, 32]),
 array([24, 31]),
 array([31, 31]),
 array([ 2, 31]),
 array([32, 32]),
 array([22, 32]),
 array([46, 30]),
 array([40, 32]),
 array([20, 31]),
 array([ 4, 32]),
 array([31, 31]),
 array([35, 30]),
 array([37, 32]),
 array([ 1, 32]),
 array([31, 31]),
 array([44, 30]),
 array([24, 32]),
 array([40, 32]),
 array([31, 30]),
 array([ 2, 31]),
 array([47, 32]),
 array([42, 32]),
 array([36, 30]),
 array([ 8, 31]),
 array([19, 30]),
 array([42, 31]),
 array([48, 31]),
 array([ 4, 30]),
 array([47, 32]),
 array([30, 32]),
 array([47, 31]),
 array([29, 31]),
 array([29, 31]),
 array([17, 32]),
 array([24, 32]),
 array([46, 30]),
 array([ 2, 30]),
 array([ 4, 30]),
 array([27, 30]),
 array([ 1, 31]),
 array([30, 32]),
 array([ 5, 32]),
 array([25, 32]),
 array([35, 30]),
 array([23, 31]),
 array([36, 31]),
 array([41, 30]),
 array([17, 30]),
 array([26, 30]),
 array([19, 30]),
 array([22, 31]),
 array([ 2, 31]),
 array([23, 32]),
 array([30, 30]),
 array([ 3, 31]),
 array([40, 30])]
```

except the arrays I need to do this with are way larger. (But only around 5% will be under the distance limit, as in the example) How can I do this most efficiently?

Comment: You may be interested in a *quadtree*.

Comment: You can avoid lots of calculations by only calculating / filtering on the distance squared (drop the root calculation, and square the distance input of the filter)
You can also try to keep the dsitance precalculated int the array, that would slightly slowdown insertion,s but save lots of time on any subsequent filtering.

Comment: also, the data generation is something I would do separately from the testing / benchmarking of the distance filter. It's probably significant here.

Comment: A little gain: once you have found a near `coord_a` points, you don't need to consider the other `coord_a` points.

Comment: Another simple way to speed up: sort both arrays according to `x` values. Then, for a given `coord_b.x`value, you only need to consider the `coord_a.x` in the range `(coord_b.x - distance, coord_b.x + distance)`

Comment: @Damien You'd probably only need to sort the `a` array.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sorting `a` is most important effectively. What I had in mind is that sorting `b` array may accelerate finding the `a` point at distance `coord_b.x - distance`, as it would be very near the point found for the previous `b` point.

Comment: @Damien Perhaps. There may also be some mileage in using `y` as a secondary sort key.

Comment: You can try cpu to memory trade off: create x-y grid with acceptable resolution, with zeros, mark cells around points in `a` (in 5 distance) as `1` and simply check value in appripriate cell for any point in `b`.

Comment: I think there is also an error in your code: in your double loop, you possibly add `b_filter.append(coord_b)` repeatedly (once for each `a` point that matches by distance).

Comment: I have created a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109987/list-all-points-within-distance-to-line) which is more focused on my exact problem. Decided not to delete this one since it's accrued 4 answers, which may be useful to someone

Answer (score 4):

One of the best ways to do that is by using the excellent [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). It does the whole thing for `a`: 1000 points and `b`: 200K points in **114 ms**. That includes: building the kd-tree, querying it, and filtering `b` for distances within the radius.

(**Important**: use `scipy >= 1.6.0`, where the Python implementation of `KDTree` has been replaced by `cKDTree`. See the [release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.6.0.html#scipy-spatial-improvements)).

```py
# please use scipy >= 1.6.0
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

tree = KDTree(a)
radius = 10
dist, idx = tree.query(b, k=1, distance_upper_bound=radius + 1)

b_filtered = b[dist <= radius]
```

### Explanation

- We use `tree.query()` with `distance_upper_bound=radius + 1` so as to *include* points that are exactly at the given radius (the behavior of `.query()` is to return points that are *strictly less than* the upper bound).
- We then filter for distances less or equal to radius.
- Of course, if you are interested about points where `dist < radius`, then no need to add 1, but it doesn't hurt since you have to filter anyway in the next step (points for which there is no close neighbor get `+inf` as distance).

### Timing

```py
a = np.random.randint(50, size=(1000, 2))
b = np.random.randint(50, size=(200_000, 2))

radius = 10
%timeit b_filtered = b[KDTree(a).query(b, k=1, distance_upper_bound=radius + 1)[0] <= radius]
# 114 ms ± 17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to improve your code is to avoid the `sqrt` here:

```
return np.sqrt(squ_dist_x + squ_dist_y)
```

Just return the sum and then compare against 25.

BTW:

This seems wrong

```
    squ_dist_x = (coord_a[0] - coord_b[1])**2
                                       ^
                                      [0] ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Using broadcasting you could create an index that indicate which coordinate are closer than `n` unit:

```
# Minimal distance:
n = 5
# Creation of the index:
ind = (((b[None,:]-a[:,None])**2).sum(2)**0.5<=n).sum(0) > 0
# Get the result:
b_filter = b[ind]
```

Where
`b[None,:]-a[:,None]` return a `(5,1000,2)` array containing the coordinate difference. Then we simply apply the euclidian distance formula and we check if at least one value of `a` is closer from `b` than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you want to do it in pure numpy, here is a vectorized (but naive) expression:

```py
b_filtered = b[np.any(np.square(b[:, None] - a).sum(axis=2) <= radius**2, axis=1)]
```

But this is `O(m * n)` for `m`, `n` points in `a`, `b`, respectively.  For `m, n = 1000, 200_000`, it takes over 6 seconds.

The [other answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108327) that uses `scipy.spatial.KDTree` is much faster (it cuts down a lot of the calculation) and does it in 114ms.